# markov property for stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, markov

Suppose the stochastic equation：
\begin{equation*}
d X(u)=\beta(u,X(u))d u+\gamma(u,X(u))d W(u).
\end{equation*}
Suppose $X(T)$ is the solution of above stochastic differential equation with initial condition $X(t)=x$ and $h(x)$ is a Borel-measurable function. Denote by
$$g(t,x)=E^{t,x}h(X(T))$$
We assume $E^{t,x}|h(X(T))|<\infty$

Let $X(u)$ is the solution of above  stochastic differential equation with initial condition given at time $0.$

Use the `markov property` of $X(t),$ we have existing $g(t,x)$ s.t
$$E[h(X(T))|\mathcal{F}(t)]=g(t,X(t))$$

My question is are those two $g(t,x)$ same? Since we want to use `Feynman-Kac equation`, but I am not sure whether it is true for first
$$g(t,x)=E^{t,x}h(X(T)).$$
since the proof of `Feynman-Kac equation` needs the martingale of $g(t,X(t)),$ but I don't think here $g(t,X(t))$ is martingale?

Comment: Have a look at Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance II Theorem 6.3.1. It  states that $\mathbb{E}[h(X(T))|\mathcal{F}(t)] = \mathbb{E}^{t,x}[h(X(T))]$ (without proof)

Comment: A conditional expectation of the form $Y_t = \Bbb{E} [ f(X_T) \vert \mathcal{F}_t ]$ (with no explicit dependence on $t$ inside $f$) will always be a martingale by the tower property, right? Just compute $\Bbb{E}[Y_t \vert \mathcal{F}_s ]$ to convince yourself that it is indeed equal to $Y_s$. Of course this is assuming the process is adapted to the filtration

Comment: @zer0hedge but in the proof of `Kolmogorov backward equation` we use $g(t,x)=E^{t,x}h(X(T))=\int^{\infty}_0h(y)p(t,T,x,y)d y,$ that is the first definition, and we will still use the martingale of $g(t,x).$

Comment: @Quantuple Yeah, I am sure $E[h(X(T))|\mathcal{F}(t)]=g(t,X(t))$ is martingale, my question is whether $g(t,x) = E^{t,x}h(X(T))$ is martingale, those two $g(t,x)$ are different, and we will use the martingale of later $g(t,x)$ to prove `Kolmogorov backward equation.`

Comment: "Note that there is nothing random about $g(t,x)$; it is an ordinary (actually, Borel-measurable) function of the two dummy variables t and x" Shreve, p.266

Comment: @zer0hedge then how to prove $g(t,x) = E^{t,x} h(X(T))$ satisies the `Feynman-Kac equation.`

Comment: @zer0hedge if I replace $x$ by $X(t)$ in $g(t,x),$ are those two random variables $g(t,X(t))$ and $E[h(X(T))|\mathcal{F}(t)]$ same?

Comment: Yes. Theorem 6.3.1 states that. My first comment above is not literally correct but means exactly that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, we assume that
\begin{align*}
g(t, x) = \mathbb{E}\left(h(X_T) \mid X_t = x \right).
\end{align*}
Note that, by [Shiryaev](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387945490), $g(t, x)$
is a Borel measurable function such that, for any Borel measurable set $A$,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{X_t \in A\}} h(X_T) d\mathbb{P} &= \int_A g(t, x) \mathbb{P}_{X_t}(dx),
\end{align*}
where $\mathbb{P}_{X_t}(dx)$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure generated by the distribution function of $X_t$, that is, for any Borel measurable set $B$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_{X_t}(B) = \mathbb{P}(X_t \in B).
\end{align*}
It can also be shown that (see Page 196 of [Shiryaev](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387945490), starting with indicator and simple functions, then, by monotone convergence theorem, to all positive functions, and, by decomposition, to all integrable measurable functions),
\begin{align*}
\int_A g(t, x) \mathbb{P}_{X_t}(dx) = \int_{\{X_t \in A\}} g(t, X_t) d\mathbb{P}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\{X_t \in A\}} h(X_T) d\mathbb{P} = \int_{\{X_t \in A\}} g(t, X_t) d\mathbb{P}.
\end{align*}
In other words,
\begin{align*}
g(t, X_t) = \mathbb{E}(h(X_T) \mid X_t) = \mathbb{E}(h(X_T) \mid \mathcal{F}_t),
\end{align*}
by the Markov property. Moreover, $\{g(t, X_t), \, 0\le t \le T \}$ is obviously a martingale.